# Android date remove GMT from DateTime

Tags: android, datetime, gmt

i need to remove "GMT" from a string like this one "2012-07-15 17:00 GMT".
Try to use this code, but testDate returns null.
Can anyone help ?

Thank you

```
    String date = "2012-07-15 17:00 GMT";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
        Date testDate = null;
        try {
            testDate = sdf.parse(date);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Solved !!!  Sorry guys. I have "yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm" in my code. My mistake. Works fine when i correct the code to just MM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

will this help ?

```
String date = "2012-07-15 17:00 GMT";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm z");
Date testDate = null;
try {
    testDate = sdf.parse(date);
}catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(testDate);

sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
date = sdf.format(testDate); 
System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but was a simple error on my code. Sorry.

Comment: @filipe i mentioned that error and corrected in my code sample above, 7mins before your comment. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since you apparently start with a String why not just cut off the last four characters, with String.substring() for example?

```
date = date.substring(0, date.length() - 4);
```

You could also confirm that `" GMT"` exists:

```
int index = date.indexOf(" GMT");
if(index > -1)
    date = date.substring(0, index);
```

If you are not changing the date's format there is no need to use the extra SimpleDateFormat and Date classes.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but was a simple error on my code. Sorry.